# Can I use jdbc without jar drivers?

Tags: java, jdbc

Profesor in my University send us the task related to graphs where he says :

data for the task are stored in database. Connection to this database is made by line of codes:

```
  String database = <connection_string>; // 
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database);
```

where

```
 <connection_string> is command line param.
```

Nobody knows which of database he is going to use in his environment and another important thing is that running program should be released only with two files

```
 path.java
 main.java
```

program have to run after this line in comand line:

```
 java Main <connection_string>
```

My question is: How to implement such funcitonality without knowledge about kind of database ? Is it possible to run connection to database without any jdbc external jar ?

Thanks for help

Comment: "Nobody knows which of database he is going to use in his environment ..." What about the professor himself?

Comment: No, you can't use JDBC without a driver. I would assume that your professor is expecting you to setup your dev environment so that you can connect to some database *you* chose. But he also expects the your code to not contain any environment specific parts (e.g. hardcoded JDBC URL, hardcoded DBMS system etc). I would further assume that he will take care of providing a proper classpath including a JDBC driver) when he runs your program.

Comment: ok so next question is can I implement connection to database without specify hardcode of my database type? I mean can I write the code which will be running the same in mysql and after changing jdbc jar e.g. oracle as well ?

Comment: Could you paste just the scheme of ```database```? Mysql, for example, uses jdbc:mysql.

Comment: You can use the JDBC data pool configured in the server. This way, you don't need to include the jar in your application's classpath. But you may still need to know the SQL dialect. Can anyone correct me on this? Thanks.

Comment: @user1985532 Having the right JDBC driver on the classpath and a JDBC url that is supported by that driver is sufficient. You only need to use the JDBC (`java.sql`) API; no need to hardcode anything.